# Invalid length for a Base-64 char array error in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

In an remote server I have added this `redirect` to my web server:

On `index.aspx` web page where the value of `querystring` **UserNumber** is **encrypted**:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("http://.../default.aspx?UserNumber=" + Encrypt(Request.QueryString["UserNumber"].ToString().Trim()));
}
```

The web page `index.aspx` redirects on the authentication page where the value of `querystring` **UserNumber** is **decrypted**.

I ran several tests and I have problem with this **UserNumber**: `a425033` or `A425033`.

When the value of **UserNumber** is `a425033` or `A425033` the web page for authentication print this error:

[image]

The error is:

```
Invalid length for a Base-64 char array
```

My code below.

Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

```
private string Encrypt(string clearText)
{
    string EncryptionKey = "Some String";

    if (Request.QueryString["UserNumber"] != null)
    {
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { /*Some Bytes*/ });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return clearText;
    }
    else
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Msg", "alert('No user.');window.location='http://.../main.aspx';", true);
        return null;
    }
}

private string Decrypt(string cipherText)
{
    string EncryptionKey = "Some String";

    if (Request.QueryString["UserNumber"] != null)
    {
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { /*Some Bytes*/ });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return cipherText;
    }
    else
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Msg", "alert('No user.');window.location='http://.../main.aspx';", true);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. You can **always** feed the output of `Convert.ToBase64String()` to `Convert.FromBase64String()`, so you're simply not feeding the latter a base64-encoded string. Perhaps it's the fact that you reuse the same query string parameter (namely `UserNumber`) for both the encrypted and unencrypted form. Anyway you may want to reconsider whether you actually want to reinvent the wheel called "authentication" yourself. Your query string parameters will end up in proxy servers and browser histories. Very, very insecure.

Comment: Base64 encoded strings cannot be included directly in URL query strings because they include characters that are interpreted as special (e.g. "+"). You will need to URL-encode the Base64 data before putting it in the query string, or use an alternate URL-safe variant of Base64.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Decrypt(Request.QueryString["UserNumber"].ToString().Replace(" ", "+"))
```

I hope to have been helpful in solving your problem.